# Privacy notice on google sheets published

Tags: google-sheets, privacy

Is it possible / recommended to add a GDPR notice in a shared google sheets, which is published to web for those who hold the link?
The data contained are a live timetable of arrivals/departures of vessels, shared among stakeholders in the port, not requiring sign up unlike other services which will also charge subscribers. I don't see any protected data inside the sheet and is not sharing any of them.
I was thinking of adding a link in the first row with a proper policy related, but in fact I don't now what to guarantee since this service is one way only.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really one-way. It might be read-only, but everyone who visits any google doc is identifiably & persistently tracked by google, and that data is used to target ads, so yes, any use of google docs should carry such a warning, though it should really be google itself issuing that warning rather than you.

Comment: Thank you, I meant one-way since the sheet was shared as read only, at the beginning I used to share it to certain users only, then, taking into account that in the publish mode you don't see the row's and col's names I opted for the last option. I'm now puzzled by this GDPR regulation in force, assumed that none of my data are privacy related, I cannot find any resource related to a warning on the matter (Useless maybe). Google has been working hard on the policy review, it looks strange to me that publishing docs on the web is not addressed.

Comment: It's not publishing docs that GDPR applies to (unless the docs contain personal data), it's Google tracking visitors doing it that presents a problem.